# CodeIgniter all the pages redirecting to homepage but url change in url bar properly

Tags: codeigniter

CodeIgniter all the pages redirecting to homepage but url change in url bar properly.
Please help me.How to solved this problem

Comment: this problem solve..  $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";

Comment: I would be helpful if your share your code so that we can properly analyze the probelm your facing..